# React Native stuck at Starting Packager

Tags: node.js, react-native

i'm new to react native and i was trying to build an app to see how it works,i followed the steps given here

[Getting Started with React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

till npm start,everything seems to be fine,after i type npm start,it says

> 12:08:53 PM: Starting packager...

and gets stuck at that,am i doing something wrong,I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

any inputs would be helpful

Comment: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/203

Comment: @chedabob followed that already

Answer (score 3):

It was fixed by runnig

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=10000
```

See this site:

https://forums.expo.io/t/packager-not-loading-on-linux/2034/3

Comment: how you can do this on windows?

Answer (score 1):

everyone has a different solution, depending on the problem.I have a few step that work for me.I just run this command on console:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

> wait until console display like image below:

[image]

> after that press `Ctrl + C` and run `npm start` or `yarn start` or other command to run your react-native project.