# Stuck in "Starting packager" - React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

When I run the get started React Native project ([you can see here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)) the `npm start` script stucks on `Starting packager`

I already read this topics about the problem:

[react-community issue: 203](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/203)

[react-native-stuck-at-starting-packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942997/react-native-stuck-at-starting-packager)

[react-community issue: 302](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/352)

But no one of the solutions helped me.
I tried to change the number of watchers, but didn´t work.
I tried to install the watchman but hasn´t helpfull.

Some enviroment informations:

S.O.: Linux 64bits
Node v: v7.10.0

Could anyone help me?

Comment: which JDK version are you using?

Comment: Its the latest: 15.6.1

Comment: Have you tried `react-native run-android`?

Comment: Try installing the older version of React Native. As I was facing the same problem but was quickly resolved after I installed the older version.

Comment: I know it's not the permanent solution to the problem but I realized something strange. after running <code>npm start</code> when it shows "starting/running packager." just press 'q' it will display the QR code, but it won't display the QR code automatically if you don't press 'q', it will just say "starting/running packager".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem just starting with *create-react-native-app* on Ubuntu 17.10 and finally got it working on Linux.

First of all, update your node version. Check inside the project with `react-native info` you have something similar to:

```
Environment:
  OS: Linux 4.13
  Node: 8.9.1
  Yarn: 1.3.2
  npm: 5.5.1
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: N/A
  Android Studio: Not Found

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.0.0-beta.5 => 16.0.0-beta.5
  react-native: ^0.49.5 => 0.49.5
```

For a fresh Ubuntu install you'll need the following dependencies to build Watchman:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev libssl-dev autoconf automake libtool
```

Build Watchman from source:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
$ cd watchman
$ git checkout v4.9.0  # the latest stable release
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Next, this:

```
$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_instances=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
$ echo fs.inotify.max_queued_events=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

And finally, you can run `yarn start` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay time to answer, but my problem was solved. I only updated my node version and ran the following command:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=10000
```