# Stuck at starting packager, getting started to react native, windows 8.1

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and I was following their getting started guide but when I  typed npm start to run my Project, it says Starting packager and no progress at all. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Note: I was tethering my phone to my pc and trying to use the expo app to run the project but it says starting packager on my terminal.

Comment: This Problem Has Been Solve, See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724521/react-native-stuck-starting-packager